# Replacing RouteData value in Asp.Net Core ActionFilter does not affect [ApiController] validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am implementing HashIds, with the goal of transparently converting entity Ids into short hashes for use in the API.

**The Goal:**

- A request to`/api/tag/dY7je` should have the effect of `/api/tag/1` (or w/e the has converts out to)
- The controller action should still require an `int`: `public ActionResult<TagViewModel> Get(int id)`

**The Problem:**

I've created an `ActionFilterAttribute` that intercepts the request, and converts the `hash` to the appropriate `id`, and changes the `RouteData` to match. However, even after changing the `RouteData` any controller with`[ApiController]` still returns an error saying `"The value 'dY7je' is not valid."`. **If I remove `[ApiController]`, the modified value goes through to the controller action and all is well.**

**The Question:**

What data is `[ApiController]` looking at that I can modify through my `ActionFilter` to avoid this issue, and how do I do that? I've searched through the `ActionExecutingContext` and am unable to find the value there.

**My Rough Action Filter:**

```cs
    public class HashIdFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IOrderedFilter
    {
        public new int Order => int.MinValue;

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            foreach ((string paramKey, object value) in context.RouteData.Values)
            {
                if (paramKey.EndsWith("id", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    int id = HashIdsUtility.DecodeInt(value as string);
                    context.RouteData.Values[paramKey] = HashIdsUtility.DecodeInt(id);
                    context.ActionArguments[paramKey] = HashIdsUtility.DecodeInt(id);
                }
            }

            base.OnActionExecuting(context);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use a `ResourceFilter` which executes before any `ActionFilters`. [MSDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#resource-filters)

```cs
    public class HashIdFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IOrderedFilter, IResourceFilter
    {
        public new int Order => int.MinValue;

        public void OnResourceExecuted(ResourceExecutedContext context)
        {
            return;
        }

        public void OnResourceExecuting(ResourceExecutingContext context)
        {
            ProcessRouteData(context.RouteData);
        }

        private void ProcessRouteData(RouteData routeData)
        {
            foreach ((string paramKey, object value) in routeData.Values)
            {
                if (paramKey.EndsWith("id", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    routeData.Values[paramKey] = HashIdsUtility.DecodeInt(value as string);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```